# Form's field modified date

Tags: sharepoint

My Teams form has several fields including `[Status]`. I want to add filed showing date-time of the last change of the `[Status]` but only field formulas could be used. Are there any functions or accessible form properties that would allow capturing modification of `[Status]` while ignoring all other changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new workflow on editing an item and then check if the status is changed or not and then if yes, update the "lastStatusUpdatedDate", with Nintex workflow it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use this api to get versions and filter what you want:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
        "/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('JobTitles')/items(1)/versions?$select=Title,VersionLabel",
    async: false,
    headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
    },
    complete: function(request) {
        console.log("CurrentUser: " + JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));
    },
    error: function(request) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, 4));
    }
});
```

the result is sth like this:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "Title":"Web Developer",
            "VersionLabel":"2.0"
        },
        {
            "Title":"Application Developer",
            "VersionLabel":"1.0"
        }
    ]
}
```